# node express get route

Tags: node.js, express

I need to create express route for the following url:
www.somesite.com/some-text-goes-here-id

In this case i want to have to parameters:
text: some-text-goes-here
id: id

Official documentation states the following example:

```
Route path: /flights/:from-:to
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/flights/LAX-SFO
req.params: { "from": "LAX", "to": "SFO" }
```

However in my case i need to have multiple '-' and only the last one should be id ...

This would be example

```
Route path: /flights/???
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/flights/some-text-goes-here-123
req.params: { "from": "some-text-goes-here", "to": "123" }
```

Im not sure if this is even possible to do this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out pretty easy way to do it:

```
Route path: /site/*-:id
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/site/some-text-goes-here-123
req.params: { "0": "some-text-goes-here", "id": "123" }
```

And if i just want to handle id below goes another route:

```
Route path: /site/:id
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/site/123
req.params: { "id": "123" }
```

Only downside here is that first param is unnamed "0".

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> Since the hyphen (-) and the dot (.) are interpreted literally, they
>   can be used along with route parameters for useful purposes.

So you can write just

```
Route path: /flights/some-text-goes-here-:id
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/flights/some-text-goes-here-123
req.params: { "id": "123" }
```

Answer (score 0):

that is not possible. You can either have

```
 /flights/:from/:to
 then you can have 
 req.params: { "from": "some-text-goes-here", "to": "123" }
```

or have

```
 /flights/:from-to-dest
then you can have 
req.params: { "from-to-dest": "some-text-goes-to-123" }
and then split the text  by delimiter -to-  and take 2nd token 
or split just by  - and take  last token.
```